# font-awesome webpack SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: npm, webpack, font-awesome, react-starter-kit

I'm new to webpack and I'm having trouble getting font-awesome to install in my React set up.

```
Webpack V2.2.1
React starter kit
```

I've run:

```
npm install font-awesome --save-dev
```

Then in my main `.scss` file, I'm calling:

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

And in my `webpack.config.js` I've got:

```
...
    test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
...
```

But on compile: `yarn start` I get the error:

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
..\node_modules\font-awesome\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { n�
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (..\build\webpack:\external "font-awesome\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot":1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (..\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 4b3091487663b7b04c64:19:1)
```

Is this a problem with my webpack setup? A problem with the loaders? Or a problem with paths? Or a problem with the fonts themselves?

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Did you try to use relative path,instead of the `~path`.

Answer (score 1):

As [wuxiandiejia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4675056/wuxiandiejia) said, the problem was solved here by using a relative path - Even though looking at the error output, webpack was already looking in the correct place with the ~ declaration. Strange.

So instead of:

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

I've used:

```
$fa-font-path: "../../../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "../../../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

And all seems to work!

Comment: Any URL containing a ~ will be interpreted as a module request. Anything after the ~ will be considered the request path. see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils#urltorequest